# Why can't I use integers in the pow() function?

Tags: c, function, integer, int, pow

*Just a disclaimer, I am a newbie with these things. I've only really just made the leap into C, and into programming in general, so please regard that, thank you.*

Hello, Stack Overflow. I have a piece of code here that for whatever reason doesn't want to work properly. The `pow()` function does not seem to like the way I input integers to be used, and my IDE tells me that the type of argument for argument 1 (the argument that holds an integer) is incompatible. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a beginner's mistake and I'm simply missing something? Can you use integers as arguments in the `pow()` function?

Here's the line of code I am using. Also, just to note I'm attempting to make a program that takes an integer and squares it, communicating to the user via `printf("text")` as a very basic project.

`SquaredIV = pow(&InputVar, 2);`

I can post more lines of code if need be, but for now I'm just going to leave this. Please help me out with this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you use integer as arguments to `pow` function?`

Yes, you can. The integer value is implicitly converted to a floating point value of the right type.

In your case:

```
SquaredIV = pow(&InputVar, 2);
```

the problem is `&InputVar` is not of an integer type but of a pointer type as `&` unary operator yields a pointer to the operand object.

Comment: Okay, so I listened to you and you were right; I had put a pointer instead of an integer. While this rectified a problem it revealed a new one: the `printf()` line that asks the user to input a number comes after a number is printed instead of before, when the program is first run! How do I make it so that the command shows the printf() line first?

Comment: Here is the code, by the way. EDIT: Leaving it [in a pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/h7fJmxK7) beacuse the formatting is driving me crazy. Sorry.

Comment: @E101K well what about just inverting the `scanf` and the `printf` statements in your program?

Comment: That didn't work, it produced the exact same result.

Comment: @E101K may I suggest you to open a new question with a compilable test case program with the result you get and the result you expect?

Comment: Okay, will do. First I'll try any solutions I find on the website or google beforehand. That doesn't matter, though. What matters is the problem I queried about is pretty much solved. Thanks. :)

Comment: @E101K: If your problem is solved, you should accept an answer by clicking the check mark. You can also upvote one or more answers if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In c `&` is the `address-of` operatior it will yield the address of `inputvar`  pow will not be able to do anything useful with that..

the code should have near the start.

```
#include <math.h>
```

and then later in the file

```
SquaredIV = pow(InputVar, 2);
```

THat's not actually using an integer as input to pow, what will happen is that the compiler will find the definition of pow in math.h and know it needs to convert the `int` into a `double` (double precision floating point) and send that to pow.  Pow will return a result as a `double` and the compilwe will know to convert this into whatever type  `SquaredIV` is.

The usual (ans most efficient) way to square an integer is to multiply it by itself.

```
SquaredIV = InputVar*InputVar;
```